# JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I did a Java appliction using spring , hibernate and Jaxb.

```
JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
JDBCExceptionReporter - Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
JDBCExceptionReporter - Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

I have got the above error when i attempt to connect the database multiple times through loop. It is for working fine up to 50 Requests but getting error's when the looping is more then 50.

Am using java 1.7 and Tomcat 7.0

Comment: use connection pooling concept

Comment: try to close your connections

Comment: Please show code contains connection.

Answer (score 5):

```
JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
```

This might came for various reasons:

1. In many cases, the main problem is the limitation of connections. 
   If you have a interaction and don't use **connection pool**, probably in the database the limit of connection was reached.
2. Other situation is, in `JDBC` palette if the number of connections (default 100) is more than number of BW jobs (default 0 for infinite).

**Important: "Generally one needs to close the statement or `Resultset` before reusing them".**