# JDBC MySQL Connection Issue - Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Tags: java, mysql, azure, jdbc, hikaricp

I have a rest service application running the Java Spring framework. The application depends on a connection to an external MySQL DB, which is connected via JDBC.

My issue is maintaining a solid connection between the rest service and the MySQL db. I have what I consider a rudimentary connection failsafe in place that looks something like:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    if(connection == null){
         this.buildConnection();
    }
    else if(!connection.isValid(10)){ //Rebuild connection if it is no longer valid
        connection.close();
        this.buildConnection();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Using this method should ensure that the connection is valid before any query is executed. My problem is that I periodically get an exception thrown when calling this method:

> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up. SQLState: 08001. ErrorCode: 0.

The things that have me super perplexed about this are:

1. This error only happens periodically. Many times the connection works just find.
2. I test this same application on my developer machine and this error never occurs.

I custom configured the MySQL DB on my own server, so I control all its config options. From this I know that this issue isn't related to the maximum number of connections allowed, or a connection timeout.

**Edit - Update 1:**

- This service is hosted as Cloud Service on Microsoft Azure platform.
- I accidentally set it up as an instance in Northern Europe, while the DB is located in North America - probably not related, but trying to paint the whole picture.
- Tried the advice at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813522/jdbcexceptionreporter-sql-error-0-sqlstate-08001) with no success. Not using thread pools, and all ResultSets and Statements/PreparedStatements are closed after.

**Edit - Update 2**

After some refactoring, I was able to successfully implement a HikariCP Connection Pool as outlined by @M.Deinum below. Unfortunately, the same problem persists. Everything works great on my local machine, and all Unit Tests pass, but as soon as I push it to Azure and wait more than a few minutes between requests, I get this error, when trying to grab a connection from the pool:

> springHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 38268ms.  SQLState: 08S01. ErrorCode: 0.

My HikariCP configuration is as follows:

```
//Set up connection pool
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://dblocation");

//Connection pool properties
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("user", "Username");
prop.setProperty("password", "Password");
prop.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate", "false");
prop.setProperty("useSSL","true");
prop.setProperty("requireSSL","true");
config.setDataSourceProperties(properties);

config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
config.setPoolName("springHikariCP");
config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(5000); 

config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");

dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a connection pool with a validation query and some automatic reconnect features? Looks like you are trying to hack around yourself.

Comment: I have no good reason why I'm not using thread pools (still getting my feet under me with JDBC), but from what I [have read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667289/why-does-autoreconnect-true-not-seem-to-work),  autoreconnect with MySQL isn't reliable. The `connection.isValid(int)` method is reliable from what I know. Your comment implies that using a connection pool could potentially eliminate low level details like this - is this in fact the case?

Comment: Yes. Also depending on the connection pool you either use a query of it uses is valid (I recommend HikariCP as a pool). Which should automatically remove invalid connection from the pool creating fresh ones when needed. Hence you don't really need auto reconnect just a proper pool

Comment: You shouldn't be using the driver/jdbcurl combo but the datasource class instead (as also explained on the wiki of HikariCP) that is really the recommended way. (I'll modify my answer with your settings. One thing to note is that `HikariDataSource` extends `HikariConfig` saves you some code.

Comment: Also for the test query use `/* ping */ select 1` of just `/* ping */` as that will trigger a ping instead of a query execution. Might differ a little in behavior.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use the test query at all as that will not use the JDBC4 mechanism which with `isValid` which will be used by default if no query is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a proper JDBC Connection Pool like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) that together with a validation query which will execute on correct intervals should give you fresh and proper connections each time.

Assuming you are using Spring and xml to configure the datasource.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName"       value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It by default validates connections on checkout. I suggest a try out.

As you are using java bases config I suggest the following

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setPoolName("springHikariCP");
    ds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    ds.setLeakDetectionThreshold(5000);
    ds.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("url", url);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", username);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", true);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", 250);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 2048);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("verifyServerCertificate", false);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", true);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("requireSSL", true);

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I Implemented this, but still doesn't solve the problem. Added additional details to the question above.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use a `connectionTestQuery` as that disable the JDBC4 `isValid` check.  You still might see the error but your application should still work imho.

Comment: Ok so I figured it out, and the answer is super close to this, but there is a key config option missing that did the trick. Is it kosher to edit your answer to include it, then accept it? Or should I add my own answer all together?

Comment: Well If you tell what is the key config option I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Key config options that made it work are:
`ds.setMaximumPoolSize(5);`
`ds.setMaxLifetime(30000);`
`ds.setMinimumIdle(5);`
`ds.setIdleTimeout(30000);` This basically ensures that there are always 5 connections in the pool that are never idle for more than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be caused by the system variable `wait_timeout` of MySQL.

For MySQL [5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), [5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), [5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), [5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), the default value for `wait_timeout` is 28800 seconds (8 hours), and the maximum value for `wait_timeout`:

- Linux : 31536000 seconds (365 days, one year)
- Windows : 2147483 seconds (2^31 milliseconds, 24 days 20 hours 31 min 23 seconds)

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it. This timeout applies only to TCP/IP and Unix socket file connections, not to connections made using named pipes, or shared memory.

So I think you can try to use a jdbc connection to keep pinging  interval some seconds, or directly using a kind of JDBC Connection Pool framework to manage jdbc connections automatically.

Hope it help. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

assuming code you have now for '//Set up connection pool' is called **only once**, like bean creation, to initialize dataSource.

with that, your getConnection() would be just:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
   return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

and make sure wait_timeout in mysql is set to minute **more** than maxLifetime in hikaricp which is default **30** minutes

Hope this helps.